# VSCode open file to be locked?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

All

is it possible to have file locked when opened by VSCode ?

any extensions?

so if I check file by `handle64` from sysinternals, it will tell me something like

```
> handle64.exe -a c:\XXX.txt

code.exe pid: 123 type: File c:\XXX.txt
```

Windows solution would be fine, cross-platform would be the best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows-specific file API ([CreateFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx)) has a number of access and sharing options, so yes, technically it would be possible.  But that doesn't mean it would be desirable.   There are a number of use-cases where it is quite desirable to allow another process to read, change or delete a file while it is "open" (really visible) in vscode.

I put "open" in quotes because to achieve the behavior it currently has, vscode probably closes the file as soon as it's done reading it, intentionally avoiding the sort of behavior you seem to be asking for.  Since your question deals with a specific solution, rather than the problem motivating you, it's hard to provide more detail.

Comment: Well, there are editors where you could flip config switch and files would be locked.

Comment: Perhaps there are, but examining the implementation of vscode's fileService.ts, I don't see any indications that it has that feature, or that it would be easy to add..

Comment: EmEditor is one example with such feature. Anyway, thank you for digging through that, I accept the answer

Comment: You are welcome..   Looking at EmEditor's feature list I see it says "large file support" which allows editing files larger than memory.   It makes sense that to support such large files, it would need to be kept open at the file-system level.   .